# Is it necessary to create a sperate .APK file for x86 architectire?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio with Gradle in order to develop an application.
Is it necessary to create a different .APK to allow proper operation on X86 architecture (Asus Zenfone 2)?
As far as I understand all architectures are supported by default in the single .APK file that is built (arm, x86, ex86_64, armeabi-v7a, mips).
I know that it is possible to use splits closure in Gradle for different abi's but I would really like to avoid it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you are app is coded in Java:**

You don't have to worry about the CPU architecture it will be running on.
Indeed, the runtime (Dalvik or ART) VM insulates your code from the underlying platform.

**If you use the NDK:**

A single APK can support multiple architectures. Follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/x86-64.html) to make sure your APK includes the required libraries and support the architectures you target.

Comment: Thanks!
So what is the reason that Gradle allows split by abi's?